# Display "Time"-type response in 12h instead of 24h format Survey123 Connect

Tags: field-calculator, arcgis-survey123

I have a Survey123 Connect form where inspectors describe the position of damage to a pipe via a "Time" field. [image: It looks like this when entered.] The issue is that if they click up on the hour entry and loop back to 1 from 12, it switches to PM automatically. This wouldn't be a problem except that reading clock face position is much easier in 12h format than in 24h format. Is there a way either to remove the AM/PM distinction in the question or to fix the display after the fact?

Another solution that I came up with was to use an SVG image with twelve sectors instead of the "time" field. Unfortunately, my supervisor didn't think it would be appropriate in this situation so that's off the table.

Answer (score 0):

Storing a bearing on the pipe face using a time field is going to cause you problems at some point. Dates/times are stored as UTC in the field app, but epoch time in the feature service.  Things like changes in the viewer's time zone, daylight savings, etc. could affect the 'time' values that you have collected as bearings. Keeping these values consistent across dashboards, Survey123 reports, etc. could be a challenge.  You may be better served to simply have the users estimate the bearing of the damage between 0-360 degrees on the pipe face. You could show field users a static compass image as a reference. Add your reference image to the survey's Media folder and call it by name from the question's image column. The image-map style you mentioned would work with your compass image as well.